# Defining intersection types in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to define a version of the simply typed lambda calculus plus intersection types. I tried the following:

```
Inductive ty : Type :=
| Bool : ty
| Int : ty
| Arrow: ty -> ty -> ty
| Inters: ty ?? ty.
```

It seems that I could only add "->". Otherwise, I get a bug. How could I add a new constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something such as:

```
Inductive ty : Type :=
| Bool : ty
| Int : ty
| Arrow: ty -> ty -> ty
| Inters: ty -> ty -> ty.
```